# Separating first name, last name, and year in Python

Tags: python

I am having trouble creating this program on Python. I want it to make the first name lowercase and the last name lowercase as well but with a capital 'N'. I also am trying to get the number of characters from the first name to be added to the year.

Example: So when a user inputs ("Lynn NOLAN 1994"), Python is supposed to return, "lynnNolan1998"

So far I have:

```
def findName(s):
    index = s.find(" ")
    lowerFirst = s[ :index].lower()
    capitalizedLast = s[index+1:index-1].capitalize()
    year = s[index+1: ].strip()
num = year + len(lowerFirst)
return lowerFirst + capitalizedLast + num
```

I'm probably way off, but Im fairly new to Python.. if I could get any tips on how to fix this, that would be great!

Comment: Don't you think last 2 lines of your Python code aren't indented properly? This code won't work in it's present form.

Answer (score 2):

Python has lots of useful string methods to help with this sort of thing:

```
In [1]: s = 'Lynn NOLAN 1994'

In [2]: f = s.split()

In [3]: f[0].lower() + f[1].title() + str(int(f[2])+len(f[0]))
Out[3]: 'lynnNolan1998'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an alternative solution using [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) and [savings groups](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#grouping):

```
In [1]: import re
In [2]: s = "Lynn NOLAN 1994"

In [3]: def replacement(x):
   ...:     group1, group2, group3 = x.groups()
   ...:     return group1.lower() + group2.capitalize() + str(int(group3) + len(group1))
   ...: 

In [4]: re.sub(r"(.*?) (.*?) (\d{4})", replacement, s)
Out[4]: 'lynnNolan1998'
```

Note that in current state this solution lacks error-handling.

Answer (score 0):

Without regex:

```
>s = "Lynn NOLAN 1994"
>split_list = s.split()
>split_list[0].lower() + split_list[1].capitalize() + str(int(split_list[2]) + len(split_list[0]))
'lynnNolan1998'
```